# Python : Functional code speed is faster than pure code speed. Why?

Tags: python, heap

I'm studying heap algorithm. 
I thought a heap algorithm as a function will be slower than pure code.
So I made a test. but I found functional code is much faster than pure code.
I think this is very weird, and I don't know why.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6vxZ.png)

```
import time

def heapify(heap):
    for i in range(1, len(heap)):
        while i != 0:
            root = int((i - 1) / 2)
            if heap[i] < heap[root]:
                tmp = heap[i]
                heap[i] = heap[root]
                heap[root] = tmp
                i = root
            else:
                break
    return heap

heap = [5,2,5,0,11,12,7,8,10] * 10000

a = time.time()
for i in range(1, len(heap)):
    while i != 0:
        root = int((i - 1) / 2)
        if heap[i] < heap[root]:
            tmp = heap[i]
            heap[i] = heap[root]
            heap[root] = tmp
            i = root
        else:
            break
b = time.time()
print("func code time :", b-a)

heap2 = [5,2,5,0,11,12,7,8,10] * 10000
a = time.time()
heap2 = heapify(heap2)
b = time.time()
print("pure code time :", b-a)
print(heap == heap2)
```

Comment: Why did you think this? In general, code inside a local function scope is faster than code using entirely the global scope because local variable lookups are faster. Note, this isn't "functional" in the sense that is usually meant. In any case, again, why did you expect it to be slower inside a function?

Answer (score 8):

In CPython, local variable lookups are optimized more than global variable lookups, so putting code in a function often makes it run faster than module level code.

In a [table of timings for common operations](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#demos-and-tools), you can see that read_local and write_local are faster than their global read/write counterparts.

Comment: Would a (very) long function be faster than than an equivalent (but much shorter) function, calling multiple other functions for performing its subtasks? Or more specifically, is the function call overhead + local variable lookup in a short function (small local variable pool) greater than the local variable lookup in a function with a large variable pool? Or is is negligible? I realize this might be an independent, (partly unrelated) question.